# Datatable created with jquery doesn't show the rows after I've added them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatable, row

the js of my project is this one:

```
 for(i=1; i<=counter; i++){
            if(stop==true){
                $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:paginaAttuale+".file-creator"+".json",
                data:{
                    "numeroFile":numeroFile,
                    "counter":i,
                    "tipoFile":tipoFile,
                    "templateOption":templateOption,
                    "pathIniziale": pathIniziale
                },
                success: function(res){
                    document.getElementById("success").style.display = 'block';
                    $("#numeroFile").val(0);
                    $('input[name=pathIniziale]').val("");
                    $("#templateOption").prop('checked', false);
                    console.log(res);
                    let newRow=[];
                    let t = $('#resTable').DataTable();
                    for(var i = 0; i <= res.length; i++){
                        newRow.push([i, res[0].titolo, res[0].path]);
                    }
                    t.row.add(newRow).draw();
                    debugger;
                    
                },
                
                error: function(err){
                    document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'block';
                    debugger;
                    console.log(err);   
                }
                })
```

using the console.log I checked that res has its values and newRow is not an empty array, but even though I use draw() it doesn't create the rows on the page, I just see the thead and in the tbody it just says 1 of 1 (because in res there's just one value).
This is the HTML:

```
<table id="resTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Path</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>

    </table>
```

non of your answers work. This is what the table looks like after the ajax call [image: table without rows]

Comment: mind including all the code relevant to the issue? html and where do you define `res` as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `newRow` variable is not needed. Simply add the row data directly to the table rows.

```js
const $table = $('#resTable').DataTable({ autoWidth: false });

const res = [
  { titolo: 'Hello World', path: 'hello/world' },
  { titolo: 'Foo Bar', path: 'foo/bar' }
];

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  $table.row.add([i, res[i].titolo, res[i].path]);
}

$table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="resTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Path</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can simplify this by using `Array.prototype.map` and calling `rows.add` instead.

```js
const $table = $('#resTable').DataTable({ autoWidth: false });

const res = [
  { titolo: 'Hello World', path: 'hello/world' },
  { titolo: 'Foo Bar', path: 'foo/bar' }
];

$table.rows.add(res.map(({ titolo, path }, i) => [i, titolo, path]));
$table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="resTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Path</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: none of your answers work

Comment: @MariaScetta they work in the snippets. Are you sure your XHR (`$.ajax`) response is valid?

Comment: @Mr.Polywirl I added your snippet in my project to test it and it doesn't work, I don't understand why. So I think maybe the problem is not in the code, but somewhere else.